# Matlab: Having trouble making my solver print solutions

Tags: matlab

I wrote this code to solve a system of equations related to a circuit. I'm having trouble getting it to print the outputs.

I was writing this as a function. I'd like to be able to specify a value for C1 and call the function, **but I'd like to have the function print values before I mess with that.
**
I'm a novice with matlab, so any explainations you can provide as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated!

CODE:

```
f0 = 1200;
Q = 3;
W0 = 2*pi*f0;
TpdB = -10.5;
Tp = 10^(TpdB/20);
C1 = 680e-9;
syms R1 R2 C2 positive;
sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];
[sR1,sR2,sC2] = vpasolve(W0==1/sqrt(C1*C2*R1*R2),...
Q == 1/(sqrt((C2*R2)/(C1*R1))*sqrt((C1*R1)/(C2*R2))*sqrt((C1*R2)/(C2*R1))),...
Tp == Q*(sqrt((C1*R2)/(C2*R1))), [R1,R2,C2]);
fprintf('%e %e %e',sol);
```

Calling this function results in MATLAB calling the function and not printing the outputs.

Comment: Did you try `fprintf('%e %e %e',sC2,sR1,sR2);`?

Comment: `sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];` creates a new array `sol` that has those three values in it, but there's no fixed equivalence between `sol(1)` and `sC2`. Updating the one variable doesn't update the other. You need to think of a variable and its value being two different things. `a=b` means assign the *value* of `b` to `a`, it doesn't link the variables in any way.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 variables to solve `R1` `C1` `C2` but only 2 independent equations.

The 1st equation `W0=..` doesn't really help because it brings in a 4th parameter `W0` that is not really needed to solve for `R1` `C1` `C2`.

`vpasolve` and for the case any solver is going to need `N` independent equations to solve `N` variables.

So you can either

**1.** still solve with one of variables left as parameter, here you have to choose which one (left as parameter)

or

**2.** define a 3rd independent equation and then solve.

**3.** Any chance for readers to see the actual **circuit diagram** connecting all components?

If so please attach it to the question.

Defining the network with a concise circuit diagram defines in turn all needed equations.

Answer (score 0):

try this correction to understand how to use variables in MATLAB :

```
f0 = 120;
0;
Q = 3;
W0 = 2*pi*f0;
TpdB = -10.5;
Tp = 10^(TpdB/20);
C1 = 680e-9;
syms R1 R2 C2;

eq1 = W0==1/sqrt(C1*C2*R1*R2);
eq2 = Q == 1/(sqrt((C1*R2)/(C2*R1)));
eq3 = Tp == Q*(sqrt((C1*R2)/(C2*R1)));

[sR1,sR2,sC2] = vpasolve([eq1,eq2,eq3], [R1,R2,C2]);
sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];
fprintf('sol : %e %e %e ',sol);
% No solutions found by this function vpasolve()

disp('No solutions')
  
[sR1,sR2,sC2] = vpasolve(eq1, [R1,R2,C2]);
sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];
fprintf(' \n sol for eq1 : %e %e %e \n',sol);
% one solution is found for the equation 1



[sR1,sR2,sC2] = vpasolve(eq1, [R1,R2,C2]);
sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];
fprintf(' \n sol for eq2 : %e %e %e \n',sol);
% one solution is found for equation 2


[sR1,sR2,sC2] = vpasolve(eq1, [R1,R2,C2]);
sol = [sC2,sR1,sR2];
fprintf(' \n sol for eq3 : %e %e %e \n',sol);
% one solution is found for equation 3
```

please note that :

1. The variable `sol` should be declared after calling the `vpasolve()` function
2. The `vpasolve()` function didn't find any solutions for your system of equations